# Android. LibGDX. Черные прямоугольники вместо текстур

Tags: android, libgdx, графика, текстура

У меня есть приложение, в котором я могу отрисовывать текстуры планет.
Я могу создавать планеты, записывать из изображение на диск и добывать в качестве `Texture`. Вот как я это делаю:

```
  fun getPlanetTexture(planetDiameter: Float): Texture {
    val planetImage = FileSystem.getPlanetBodyFor(planet)
    if (!planetImage.exists()) {
      val planetBitmap = getPlanetBitmap(planetDiameter)
      FileSystem.savePlanetBody(planet, planetBitmap)
    }
    val textureFileHandle = AbsoluteFileHandleResolver().resolve(planetImage.toString())
    return Texture(textureFileHandle)
  }
```

Когда я создаю и добавляю на экран картинку таким образом, вместо нее появляется черный прямоугольник. Но стоит мне перезайти в приложение, как черный квадрат оборачивается моей красивой планеткой. (состояние приложения сохраняется при выходе, так что это то же файл, что я создал в прошлый раз).

НО, стоит мне добавить на экран новую текстуру, как она становится черной, более того, старая текстура, которая была только что планетой, тоже становится черным квадратом!

Что может быть не так?

Текстуры 256х256